# SSL: Certificate verification error on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, ssl

Bear with me here guys, I am using Flask and I have two different API services running on different IP's and ports on **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**. All I want to do is send a POST or GET request from one to another using an SSL connection.

- I am able to create cert and key files with using "`sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/name_of_key.key -out /etc/ssl/name_of_crt.crt`" command, also
  added these files here `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapi.service` in order to have SSL connection.
- My NGINX file is given below:

  ```
  server {
    listen 60000 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/name_of_cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/name_of_key.key;
    server_name IP_ADDRESS;
    location / {
      include uwsgi_params;
      uwsgi_pass unix:/home/first_api/first_api.sock;
  }}
  ```
- The problem occurs when I try to send a POST request from one API to another. My code for first API is given below:

  ```py
  from flask import Flask, jsonify
  import requests

  app = Flask(__name__)


  @app.route('/sample_api_one', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
  def service():
      data = {}
      data["message"] = "first message has arrived"
      response = requests.post('https://SECOND_API_IP_ADDRESS:57949/second_api', json=data, verify="/etc/ssl/name_of_crt.crt")

      return jsonify(response.json())
  ```
- I know that I can send my request with changing "***verify=False***" but that's not the thing I want.
  I would like to send my request with using SSL connection. Almost tried everything here but still not able to do it.
- Lastly, here is my error code when I try to run my app and send a request:

  ```
  File "/home/venv_first_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
        raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='SECOND_API_IP_ADDRESS', port=57949): Max retries exceeded with url: /second_api (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))
  ```

Comment: You're using a self-signed cert that will fail verification because, err, it's self-signed. You need a CA cert to not fail verification. Or set verify=False to avoid the issue. Or create/add your own local (private, on your intranet) CA to the trust store, and create a cert using that CA.

Comment: Can I generate on my own Ubuntu the CA cert which I need?

Comment: Go searching - have you tried searching? - I very qickly found this which I haven't tried but is along the right lines https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development. But note keys generated this way will never be trusted on the internet because your private CA doesn't have a chain of trust to a trusted public CA.